# Spring cloud gateway does not redirect on local addresses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I have been struggling for hours now on a problem related to an architecture based on Spring cloud gateway and Netflix Eureka.

Here's my Gateway code:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/")
                        .uri("http://google.com"))
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/auth-service")
                        .uri("http://10.0.2.15:8100"))
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/concert-service")
                        .uri("lb://concert-service"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Its `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8762

spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

The first path redirects well to google homepage but both others return an error 404. When I  request them directly on their host address, I get the content of the page.

By example:

- this get request on Postman works well: `http://10.0.2.15:8100/`
- but not this one: `http://10.0.2.15:8762/auth-service/`
- nor this one: `http://10.0.2.15:8762/concert-service/`

Here's the code for the Auth service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    class ServiceInstanceRestController {

        @Autowired
        private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String welcome() {
            return "Welcome on Auth microservice api.";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
        public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(
                @PathVariable String applicationName) {
            return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
        }
    }
}
```

Its `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8100

spring.application.name=auth-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

Code for Concert service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ConcertApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConcertApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    class ServiceInstanceRestController {

        @Autowired
        private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String welcome() {
            return "Welcome on Concert microservice api.";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
        public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(
                @PathVariable String applicationName) {
            return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
        }
    }
}
```

Its `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8101

spring.application.name=concert-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

They are all well registered on Eureka server

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=DEBUG
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=DEBUG
```